# Unable to deploy to cloudhub mule4 application with Gradle

Tags: gradle, deployment, anypoint-studio, mulesoft, cloudhub

I am trying to build my mule application and deploy it to cloudhub with Gradle (The Gradle version I'm using is: Gradle 4.10.2) . For this I have added the build.gradle file in my project as shown below:[image]

When I give the Gradle build command it is successful as shown below:[image]

But when I execute Gradle deploy (`gradle deploy --info`) command, it fails with following error:[image]

Any help to resolve the above issue would be appreciated.

Comment: Please use text instead of images. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question for more details on the reason.

Comment: Ok...Thanks for the info..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That Gradle has been abandoned for some years and seems to be trying to use a  CloudHub REST API endpoint that is no longer valid. If you want to use Gradle you will need a newer Gradle plugin that uses the current CloudHub API. Note that MulesSoft only supports Maven.

You can try running with `--stacktrace` as the error message suggests to find out more details about the error.

Comment: Yes....You are right....I have also come to the same conclusion for the following reasons: 1. The Plugins were last updated in 2015        2. Thus the Gradle Plugin does not support Mule 4 and latest cloudHub API        3. Also mule 3 plugins won't work with the latest version of Gradle. It works only for Gradle versions below 5.